# Is it possible to use all the outputs from a power supply at the same time?

Tags: power-supply

I wonder if is possible to utilize all power supply from this device: [Power supply](https://www.tracopower.com/int/model/txl-060-0534ti)

I need the 5V output to power a relay board for a Raspberry Pi, and the 24V output to power a motor shield, both connected to the same power supply. Is this possible or must I buy two separate power supplies?

Comment: You can use the multiple rails, as long as you respect the upper and lower limits of the power supply (all in the datasheets in the URL you provided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's why it has more than 1 output.

Sanity check : it's a 60W supply but the 5V rail is only 30W (6A) and the 24V rail is rated 1.2A (also 30W). Note the 12V rail is rated at 1.5A (18W) so there may be restrictions on using all 3 outputs at full power.

Also check : is 1.2A enough for the motor you are using on that 24V rail? Motors tend to take quite high currents when starting : that can trip the protection on some designs of power supply.

Comment: For the 24 I need 2+A...so I need a to get a better one?